Where is the function called by this url and how to set breakpoints for debugging Rancher?
When I debug Rancher, the Rancher's route cannot be found in the code and I can't find the function corresponding to the api /v3/projects/local:p-4ldrc/deployments. Does anyone know how to debug this api and where is the corresponding function?


I found it in vendor/github.com/rancher/norman/api/handler/list.go
